# Getting errors while using import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable'; in angular cli

Tags: angular6, angular-cli-v6

I have been facing this issue since yesterday and almost crowled everything on the internet for this. 
I'm facing issue while creating a service in angular cli (which i think uses angular 6).
And while creating the service and putting this line in the declaration part

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
```

I'm getting a red underlined error under this code saying that it's wrong. I have tried every possible thing out here and strongly feel that is the fault of angular. Even if it is there how can I create my own project using angular cli of an older version? Please tell me.

[image]

Comment: there is change in Rxjs import syntax.You need to change the line to
`import { Observable} from 'rxjs';`
check https://blog.angularindepth.com/rxjs-tslint-rules-for-version-6-d10e2482292d

Comment: I have did it but it didn't help with "map" .  It showed "Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Observable<Response>'." this error

Comment: you also need to change the map operator import to
`import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';`
please check the link https://www.academind.com/learn/javascript/rxjs-6-what-changed/

Answer (score 0):

Use the following command :

```
npm i --save rxjs-compat
```